# how to replace multiple chars efficiently with scala?

Tags: java, scala, replaceall

I want to replace 5 different chars to 5 different chars, and the current way im doing it looks stupid, so what would be a better way to do this?

currently:

```
 private def fixChars(str: String): String = {
    str.replaceAll("Ø","O")
    str.replaceAll("ø", "o")
    str.replaceAll("Ž","Z")
    str.replaceAll("ž","z")
    str.replaceAll("Ö","O")
}
```

?

Comment: Please define "better". Your code looks fine, except that you ignore the result of the `replaceAll` call.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose what do you mean " ignore the result"?

Comment: The method `replaceAll` returns a result that contains the _modified_ string. It does not modify the original string.

Comment: Note the important hint from @Seelenvirtuose. In addition, replaceAll is for regular expressions, for Strings just use replace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this approach will work for you and takes only one iteration to substitute all characters:

```
private def fixChars(str: String): String = {
  val substitutions = Map(
    'Ø' -> 'O',
    'ø' -> 'o',
    ...
  )
  str.map(c => substitutions.getOrElse(c, c))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could wrap the characters replacements into a map:

```
def fixChars(str: String): String = {
    val repl = Map(
      "Ø" -> "O",
      "ø" -> "o",
      "Ž" -> "Z",
      "ž" -> "z",
      "Ö" -> "O"
    )
    repl.foldLeft(str) { case (cur, (from, to)) => cur.replaceAll(from, to) } 
}
```

Not sure if it looks THAT better.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a regex and also replace with whatever string also depending on the matched piece

```
  def replaceMultiple(s: String) = {
    val pattern = "([+~:()])".r
    pattern.replaceAllIn(
      s,
      m => s"\\${m.group(0)}"
    )
  }
```